# Reversing a Wordpress themes date order

Tags: wordpress

So I still haven't been able to figure this out: Reversing the order of dates on top and thumbnails of this page: http://www.kimsquaglia.com/work/ It should behave like the home page.

Here is the code: http://pastie.org/4212608

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).  `get_terms()` can accept an order argument.

On line 48, try replacing

```
$skills = get_terms('skill');
```

with

```
$skills = get_terms('skill', 'order=DESC');
```

Comment: I'm glad that worked!  Don't forget, if it worked, you can mark this response as an accepted answer ;)